# Xcode 13.2.1 Crashes on launch on Monterey

Tags: xcode, macos-monterey

I just did a clean install on my mac with the latest MacOS Monterey, since then I had problems launching Xcode. I try to downgrade to Xcode 12 but it also can't launch with a different set of errors. I have removed the Xcode and reinstalled as well, but keep getting the errors the following errors.

When I launch Xcode I see an error stating that

Xcode quit unexpectedly. Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to apple. "

The following is the information in the bug report

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [13028]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.2.1 (19586)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-19586000000000000~2 (13C100)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       845961054
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-12-29 21:05:14.8494 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 12.1 (21C52)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        761BB2D2-9587-496F-A99B-28153F166DE4

Sleep/Wake UUID:       EFC592FD-C240-4939-B494-F1EDB25D5747

Time Awake Since Boot: 29000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3461 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dlopen(@rpath/libIDEApplicationLoader.dylib, 0x0001): tried:(security policy does not allow @ path expansion)
abort() called


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff81d9e5112 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff81da1b214 pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff81d967d10 abort + 123
3   Xcode                                  0x1019c3537 main.cold.1 + 38
4   Xcode                                  0x1019c2d42 main + 336
5   dyld                                   0x1102154fe start + 462


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000110290600  rcx: 0x00007ff7be53f978  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000103  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ff7be53f9a0  rsp: 0x00007ff7be53f978
   r8: 0x00007fe49080a038   r9: 0xfffeffffffffffff  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000103  r13: 0x00007fe49011f760  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007ff81d9e5112  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00007ff860821e00
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148 
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
    0x7ff81d9de000 -     0x7ff81da14fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <5aa1e5be-b5b8-3a02-9885-a8c99e0ca378> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7ff81da15000 -     0x7ff81da20fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <6c7561b4-4b92-3f45-921e-abe669299844> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7ff81d8e6000 -     0x7ff81d96efff libsystem_c.dylib (*) <e58814cc-dcb7-35a5-badc-e367ed3ac207> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x1019c0000 -        0x1019c3fff com.apple.dt.Xcode (13.2.1) <c1d00c9f-cea5-312a-b16d-c9bb36eebb41> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x110210000 -        0x11027bfff dyld (*) <cef5a27a-d50b-3020-af03-1734b19bc8c5> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=885.5M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=885.5M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=155.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=155.1M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            27.1M       14 
MALLOC guard page                   24K        5 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         120.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8192K        1 
VM_ALLOCATE                          8K        2 
__DATA                            18.1M      287 
__DATA_CONST                      13.8M      191 
__DATA_DIRTY                       736K      109 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       641.0M        7 
__OBJC_RO                         81.8M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3136K        2 
__TEXT                           244.5M      309 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
shared memory                        8K        1 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.2G      935 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.1G      935 



-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"Xcode","timestamp":"2021-12-29 21:05:14.00 +0800","app_version":"13.2.1","slice_uuid":"c1d00c9f-cea5-312a-b16d-c9bb36eebb41","adam_id":"497799835","build_version":"19586","platform":1,"bundleID":"com.apple.dt.Xcode","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.1 (21C52)","incident_id":"2E4381E6-5319-48ED-95E1-7B6DE4E39E11","name":"Xcode"}
{
  "uptime" : 29000,
  "procLaunch" : "2021-12-29 21:05:14.8301 +0800",
  "procRole" : "Default",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iMac15,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 29888813166473,
  "coalitionID" : 4955,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.1",
    "build" : "21C52",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2021-12-29 21:05:14.8494 +0800",
  "incident" : "2E4381E6-5319-48ED-95E1-7B6DE4E39E11",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 13028,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 29888831985917,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "Xcode",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/Xcode",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"13.2.1","CFBundleVersion":"19586","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.dt.Xcode"},
  "buildInfo" : {"ProjectName":"IDEFrameworks","SourceVersion":"19586000000000000","ProductBuildVersion":"13C100","BuildVersion":"2"},
  "storeInfo" : {"storeCohortMetadata":"10|date=1640779200000&sf=143473&pgtp=Search&pgid=osx&prpg=Genre_133005&ctxt=Search&issrch=1&imptyp=lockup&kind=macSoftware&lngid=2","itemID":"497799835","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"3397027C-A430-5AB7-960B-AD9958C5155F","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"845961054"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode",
  "crashReporterKey" : "761BB2D2-9587-496F-A99B-28153F166DE4",
  "wakeTime" : 3461,
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "EFC592FD-C240-4939-B494-F1EDB25D5747",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "asi" : {"Xcode":["dlopen(@rpath\/libIDEApplicationLoader.dylib, 0x0001): tried:(security policy does not allow @ path expansion)"],"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":294397,"threadState":{"r13":{"value":140619646367584},"rax":{"value":0},"rflags":{"value":582},"cpu":{"value":0},"r14":{"value":6},"rsi":{"value":6},"r8":{"value":140619653619768},"cr2":{"value":140704747757056},"rdx":{"value":0},"r10":{"value":0},"r9":{"value":18446462598732840959},"r15":{"value":22},"rbx":{"value":4566091264,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_main_thread"},"trap":{"value":133},"err":{"value":33554760},"r11":{"value":582},"rip":{"value":140703625531666,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"rbp":{"value":140702026824096},"rsp":{"value":140702026824056},"r12":{"value":259},"rcx":{"value":140702026824056},"flavor":"x86_THREAD_STATE","rdi":{"value":259}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":28946,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":25108,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":263,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":531728,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":123,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":13623,"symbol":"main.cold.1","symbolLocation":38,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":11586,"symbol":"main","symbolLocation":336,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":21758,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":462,"imageIndex":4}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703625502720,
    "size" : 225280,
    "uuid" : "5aa1e5be-b5b8-3a02-9885-a8c99e0ca378",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703625728000,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "6c7561b4-4b92-3f45-921e-abe669299844",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703624486912,
    "size" : 561152,
    "uuid" : "e58814cc-dcb7-35a5-badc-e367ed3ac207",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4321968128,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "13.2.1",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode",
    "size" : 16384,
    "uuid" : "c1d00c9f-cea5-312a-b16d-c9bb36eebb41",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/Xcode",
    "name" : "Xcode",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "19586"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4565565440,
    "size" : 442368,
    "uuid" : "cef5a27a-d50b-3020-af03-1734b19bc8c5",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 140703622500352,
  "size" : 15216738304,
  "uuid" : "40432a03-88d3-305f-9c0c-e7549e71d927"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=885.5M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=885.5M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=155.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=155.1M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nKernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 \nMALLOC                            27.1M       14 \nMALLOC guard page                   24K        5 \nMALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         120.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 \nStack                             8192K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE                          8K        2 \n__DATA                            18.1M      287 \n__DATA_CONST                      13.8M      191 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       736K      109 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       641.0M        7 \n__OBJC_RO                         81.8M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3136K        2 \n__TEXT                           244.5M      309 \n__UNICODE                          588K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nshared memory                        8K        1 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.2G      935 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.1G      935 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000196
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "61c11dcd2cb6041dc630dc63"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000357
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS" : "6103050cbfe6dc472e1c982a"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000066
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000090
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS" : "6193d03f2171a2330e561dfc"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000290
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}

Model: iMac15,1, BootROM 432.40.8.0.1, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 4 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 2.23f11
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M295X, AMD Radeon R9 M295X, PCIe, 4 GB
Display: iMac, Retina 5K (5120 x 2880), Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0000, 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0000, 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x142), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1710.3)
AirPort: 
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB, 500.11 GB
USB Device: USB30Bus
USB Device: My Passport 25AA
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Gaming Mouse G402
USB Device: QuickFire Rapid keyboard
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 26.1
```